# Making Directory in C Program

Tags: c, linux, function

For my assignment, I've to write a function to create a directory but I'm not allowed to use SYS functions at all! Is there any other way? I've been searching for it everywhere but didn't find anything that actually works.
The function must at least work on Linux.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly a write my code request, not a question. Please read [Ask] page first. :)

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: I've read it and I've found nothing. Every code I've seen uses library/stat.h or other system functions. And Yes, it is a write my code request because I haven't find anyway for it. If you know a function name it and I'll check out how to use it.

Comment: In my opinion, this is clearly a perfectly valid StackOverflow question and should not be closed or downvoted. It's not "write my code" since the answer can be just one or two lines pointing to the appropriate include and API call.

Comment: @ammoQ I think there could be long discussions about this ... in any case, it is not fully clear what he is asking for.

Comment: What I need is a function to create a directory without system calls. I had found the functions like mkdir (from sys/stat.h) and direct library but none of them are useful because of the restrictions I have for my assignment.

Comment: You could download the source for glibc and see how it implements `mkdir`. I haven't checked it myself, so I don't know if it includes any code that is forbidden for you.

Comment: Are you allowed to execute the `/bin/mkdir` exectuable using `system` or `exec` etc.?

Comment: You should be aware that only the system knows how to create a directory. That's because Linux supports many file systems, each with a different representation of its internal workings (inodes, directories etc.) System calls exist so  programmer can do such things without having to care for the details. If you try to do that yourself, bypassing the system and working directly with the hardware, you basically have to reimplement large parts of the operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on Linux (not sure what you mean with "sys functions", so it might be disallowed):

```
#include <sys/stat.h>    
mkdir("/tmp/foobar", 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I'm not allowed to use sys/stat.h library.

Comment: @MohammedFarahmand: `sys/stat.h` isn't a "*library*" but a header file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the `system()` function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int system(const char *command);
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use this function.

Comment: So which functions / headers are you allowed to use?

Answer (score 0):

If the limitation is "cannot use any function declared in an include file that starts with sys", this sounds more like a puzzle than a programming exercise. However...

You could write a function that first calls `fork`, then in the child calls `execl` (or another function in the `exec*` family, if that looks like a better choice). Both `fork` and `exec*` are available and declared once `#include <unistd.h>` has been run. Unfortunately, this will leave a zombie around every time you call it, since you cannot call `waitpid` to clean up after the child.

Alternatively, you could simply declare `mkdir` yourself, `int mkdir(const char*, unsigned int);`.

It is not clear to me which one of these two solutions are the worst, but neither of them is something that I would expect in anything approaching "normal code".

Comment: Yes, it's really disturbing. Most of my classmates are messaging our TAs right now... Is there any assembly code for the job?

Answer (score 0):

according to man page of `mkdir` function, https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdir it expects the path (`char *`) and mode of datatype `mode_t` as arguments, mode`mode_t` is defined in `sys/stat.h` i would try to emulate `mode_t` structure defined in the header file.http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
#include <direct.h>
int _mkdir( const char *dirname );
```

Comment: As far as i know, direct library is for microsoft windows. My program must be functional on Linux.